# macOS gcc clang

Tags: macos, gcc, clang

На macOS при вызове `clang` без параметров появляется ошибка

```
clang: error: no input files
```

НО при вызове `gcc` тоже самое

```
clang: error: no input files
```

Тоже самое и с `--version`

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Почему при явном вызове `gcc` вызывается `clang`, и как тогда использовать `gcc`

Answer (score 2):

Кто-то явно сделал диверсию (UPDATE: это, похоже, таки сборщики MacOS), но разбирать её надо по общим принципам unix-like систем. Начните с `type gcc` в bash (если шелл - bash) - оно должно рассказать, что такое gcc. Возможно, что это алиас или функция. Если так, надо найти и устранить их источник. Это может быть симлинк (например, `/usr/bin/gcc` - симлинк на `clang`). Тогда вопрос в источнике этого симлинка. Это может быть скрипт-переходник, который разбирает, что вызвать. Ну и так далее.

Если Вы знаете, какой именно GCC установлен, то можно его вызвать напрямую с указанием полного пути или просто версии (вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685887/where-is-gcc-on-osx-i-have-installed-xcode-already), какой может быть путь и как искать пакет-источник).

UPD: если нужен собственно GCC, можно поставить через homebrew.

Comment: `$ type gcc`
`gcc is /usr/bin/gcc`

`$ ls -la /usr/bin | grep gcc`
`-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel      18240 15 июл 07:29 gcc`
`lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel          5 13 сен 20:56 llvm-gcc -> clang`

Comment: Теперь сделайте `file /usr/bin/gcc`. Хотя я подозреваю по этому выводу, что он окажется скриптом, который дальше зовёт llvm-gcc или clang напрямую.

Comment: `$ file /usr/bin/gcc`
`/usr/bin/gcc: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Comment: Что говорит pkgutil про источник файла?

Comment: Как определить источник файла не знаю, но определил что установлен он был при установке системы, поскольку `Install-time` у `/bin/cp` и у `/usr/bin/gcc` одинаковый

Comment: `pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/gcc` должно назвать пакет

Comment: Да, я так и делал `pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Essentials`
`pkg-version: 10.12.6.1.1.1500089887`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69438/discussion-between-shotinleg-and-netch).